# Encountering errors when using C++ interop on old MFC/Win32 application

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, c++-cli, clr

I have inherited an old MFC/Win32 C++ application who's source code I am not supposed to edit.

This MFC application needs to host an old MFC/Win32 C++ DLL. This DLL also tries to make function calls through a Mixed-mode wrapper to a managed C++/CLI DLL. I know it sounds a little confusing, so here's a diagram of what I mean:

```
Old MFC/Win32 Application (NO CLR)

    ---> Hosting old MFC/Win32 DLL (NO CLR)

                 ---> Making function calls to Mixed-Mode wrapper (CLR)

                              ---> Sending function calls to C++/CLI DLL (CLR)
```

My problem currently is that when I try to mount an object of the C++/CLR wrapper class let's say `WrapperClass WC;`, the MFC/Win32 application encounters an "Unhandled exception."

I have a feeling that I may need to somehow host the CLR in a separate process in order to be able to make the object. Is this the right idea? Or am I completely out of whack here?

The code compiles time and this only occurs at run-time.

Any ideas?

Here is an example of the code I am trying to run:

*MFC/Win32 DLL*

```
#include "WrapperClass.h"

BOOL Test::bTest() //This function is called elsewhere within MFC/Win32 DLL
{
    DWORD dwTest;

    WrapperClass WC; //Unhandled exception here!

    return WC.FunctionToCall(dwTest); //FunctionToCall is a BOOL
}
```

*Mixed-Mode Wrapper Class*

```
BOOL WrapperClass::FunctionToCall(DWORD dw)
{
    GCHandle h = GCHandle::FromIntPtr(IntPtr(m_impl)); //m_impl def'd as void *
    CPPCLIClass^ CCC = safe_cast<CPPCLIClass^>(h.Target);

    return (BOOL)CCC->FunctionToCall(dw);
}
```

*C++/CLI DLL*

```
bool CPPCLIClass::FunctionToCall(UInt32 ui32)
{
    if (ui32 == 42)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:** 
I've managed to coax a real exception out of the program. I am now receiving a `System.IO.FileNotFound` exception with additional information stating:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occured in 
Unknown Module.

Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'CPPCLIProject,
Version=1.0.4351.29839, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its 
dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Does this mean anything? I understand that it apparently cannot find CPPCLIProject (Note: this is not the wrapper project), but then if I'm linking on the .lib file from the Mixed-mode wrapper, how would I not receive linker errors then?

Comment: What is your perceived distinction between C++/CLR and C++/CLI? The former is merely a common misspelling of the latter, i.e. they're the same thing.

Comment: I should have said Mixed-Mode DLL instead of C++/CLR, I will fix this now. Please see updated question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that the implementation of `WrapperClass::FunctionToCall()` isn't throwing the exception? It looks like you're caching the memory location of a CLR object, and then trying to call one of its members. I think the CLR is free to move objects around, so it's possible that you're trying to use an object that has moved.

If you change the implementation of `WrapperClass::FunctionToCall()` to something simple (i.e. create a CLR object, call a member function), do you still get the same unhandled exception?

**UPDATE**: Which class is in CPPCLIProject - CPPCLIClass? Assuming this project represents the C++/CLI DLL, it sounds like it just can't find the assembly to load it when it needs to call your class.

Where is this assembly on disk relative to the rest of the application? If your root EXE is unmanaged (which it sounds like it is, since it is MFC/Win32), then the CLR looks in the EXE's directory and the GAC in order to load assemblies (I don't think it looks in the Path, but I'm not positive on that).

So if the CPPCLIProject isn't in the same directory as the EXE, that could be your problem.

Comment: The first two lines of `WrapperClass::FunctionToCall` are actually part of Microsoft's implementation of this type of interop, all I did was customize it to use the same class names as I was working with. To be truly honest, I'm unsure exactly what they're accomplishing there, but it does seem to work (in their example solution at least).

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. Currently though, I can't for the life of me figure out why CPPCLIProject is not creating a .lib file for me to link on! I've tried a few different ways of forcing the .lib file out but it just doesn't seem to want to create one for me :(

Comment: Ah! I've figured out that the issue was that I was trying to link on the .lib file for CPPCLIProject which isn't supposed to be generated. The solution is as described above, all dlls must be in the same folder as the MFC application! Thanks Andy :)

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to

- run under a debugger (add the additional DLLs with debug information to the debug session)
- enable break on all (first-chance) exceptions
- trace/assert all HRESULT codes
- in general try to catch

  - C++ exceptions (`try/catch`...)
  - Windows Structured Exceptions (IIRC _*try/*_catch, but [see MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swezty51%28v=vs.80%29.aspx))

The idea is to convert the 'unkown exception' into 'known exception'.

Normally speaking there is no need to host the CLR part out of process. This is what a mixed-mode DLL is about. Then again, if this is legacy code, you might be running into complicated mixes of runtime dependencies that, shall we say, could clash.

---

Further thoughts:

If I understand correctly, you have the option to *recompile* all sources (just not touch the legacy codebase?). If so, make sure all code is compiled against the same version (think Service Packs) and type (think Static vs Dynamic/Multithread/Debug) of the runtime libraries.

While you are checking additional pathways, keep an eye on potentially conflicting dependencies on

- ATL server libs
- MFC libs (again static vs dynamic/Multithread/Debug flavours).

Comment: I tried to rebuild the MFC/Win32 application and apparently, it got worse. Now it won't even load in the MFC DLL as it used to, but it will load the version of the MFC DLL before I made any changes to it. :(

Comment: It appears that, after further digging into the source code for the application, the application attempts to run a `LoadLibrary()` on the MFC DLL which ends up returning NULL. Are there any possible explanations as to why this is happening only with my newer version of the MFC DLL and not the older (untouched) one?

Comment: Yes, certainly. Chances are you are running one of the MFC versions that link to msvcrt*.dll that **must** be loaded/initialized via manifests. This is tough business - to remember it anyways. You should be able to find your way out googling that (MSVCRT + manifest + name of your runtime (e.g. vcredist2008 etc)) and learn more about Side-By-Side cache and SxS version Policies than you ever wanted to know.

Comment: PS. See also [Potential Errors Passing CRT Objects Across DLL Boundaries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms235460(v=VS.80).aspx). I still think the _only_ sane way out is to link all components to _exactly_ the same versions of any shared libraries (and link none statically). If that fails, you could always use a process boundary as a _firewall_ - as long as you make sure you only marshall using COM+ or .NET Remoting, and refrain from any non-Win32 Interprocess business (i.e. no shared memory mapping or other tricks that may blow your cover)

Comment: @Brutick: Re: `apparently it got worse`: nope, fail early and fail loudly is way better than silently corrupt your core business!